# k6 : panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference : docker run

Tags: dockerfile, k6

```
FROM golang:1.20-bullseye as builder

RUN go install -trimpath go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest

RUN  xk6 build --output "/tmp/k6" --with github.com/grafana/xk6-browser

# Create grafana.ini file with the necessary configuration
RUN echo "wal = true" > /tmp/grafana.ini

FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y chromium

COPY --from=builder /tmp/k6 /usr/bin/k6

# Copy the grafana.ini file
COPY --from=builder /tmp/grafana.ini /etc/grafana.ini

ENV K6_BROWSER_HEADLESS=true

#ENTRYPOINT ["k6"]

WORKDIR /k6-performance-test

COPY Browser_Test/chaostestingt.js .
COPY users.json .
COPY profiles.json .

CMD ["k6", "run", "chaostestingt.js"]
```

I have the above docker file which i was using to run the k6 script ,it was working find till last week,but now throwing belwo exception

```
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0xec5b8f]
    
    goroutine 46 [running]:
    github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*Frame).requestByID(0xc00219c540, {0xc00034b350, 0x6})
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/frame.go:435 +0x54f
    github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*FrameManager).requestFailed(0xc002da4000, 0xc002c0e3c0, 0x1)
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/frame_manager.go:454 +0x4d7
    github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*NetworkManager).onLoadingFailed(0xc0009b1100, 0xc000c76300)
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/network_manager.go:375 +0x112
    github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*NetworkManager).handleEvents(0xc0009b1100, 0xc003a42720)
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/network_manager.go:347 +0x286
    github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*NetworkManager).initEvents.func1()
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/network_manager.go:330 +0x37
    created by github.com/grafana/xk6-browser/common.(*NetworkManager).initEvents
        github.com/grafana/xk6-browser@v1.4.2/common/network_manager.go:329 +0x14d
```

Note : the exception is occurring only when trying to run from docker and when ran same script from local not seeing the "invalid memory address" exception
Also there were not changes made in between                                      Its also mainly occuring when trying         await page.goto(url); (its the 2nd time we requesting this teh intial url loading having no issue ,but when tried 2nd time its causing this issue)

Comment: Sounds like a bug with xk6-browser. Does it happen with every script? Do you also build xk6@latest outside docker?

Comment: yes it happening for every script .Do you also build xk6@latest outside docker? >>no,i am using the jenkins job to run the dockerfile

Comment: So you are *not* "running the same script from local". You are are running only the last line of the code you have shown. `@latest` is not guaranteed to work in all cases, it is the development version and may contain bugs. If you can make a reproducible example, I would suggest opening an issue at GitHub.

Comment: Thank you @knittl after using previous version for the k6-browser the issue is now gone.

Comment: Please open a GitHub issue with a reproducer; the k6 maintainers will be thankful